# Patch request in Backbonejs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, backbone.js, patch

I am trying to partially update an model using patch request. I wrote like this:

```
@model.save(null, {
  silent: true
  patch: true
})
```

But the server is returning a 405 error. I couldn't figure out the reason, can anyone help?

My backend is a rails application.

Thanks

Comment: Inspect the network request on the `Network` tab in the browser Developer Tools. Is it a patch request? What is the error message from the server?

Comment: Yes it is a patch request. The response tab is empty, status is 405 method not allowed.

Comment: it's not a backbone issue, but issue with rails server, you need allow PATCH method on the server. So first you need to know which server you use and then ask new question how to allow PATCH method on it. thanks.